# None type object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before someone tells me to search the web some more, I have searched for over an hour already.

So my assignment requires me to use an imported module that contains a safeOpen function that opens a file for the main module, selectiveFileCopy. But when I call the safeOpen function, it says that the file I am trying to open is a None type, and is therefore not iterable. I'm not sure why that is.

Here's some code:

```
def safeOpen(prompt, openMode, errorMessage ):
   while True:
      try:
         open(input(prompt),openMode)
         return 
      except IOError:
         return(errorMessage)

def selectivelyCopy(inputFile,outputFile,predicate):
   linesCopied = 0
   for line in inputFile:
      outputFile.write(inputFile.predicate)
      if predicate == True:
         linesCopied+=1
   return linesCopied


inputFile = fileutility.safeOpen("Input file name: ",  "r", "  Can't find that file")
outputFile = fileutility.safeOpen("Output file name: ", "w", "  Can't create that file")
predicate = eval(input("Function to use as a predicate: "))   
print(type(inputFile)) 
print("Lines copied =",selectivelyCopy(inputFile,outputFile,predicate))
```

Comment: What line does the error occur at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return the file object itself:

```
return open(input(prompt),openMode)
```

---

Some more comments. Most parts of your code make little sense.

1. In `safeOpen`, you have an endless loop, but leave it after the first iteration unconditionally. You don't need this loop at all.
2. `safeOpen` returns either a file object or an error message. Generally functions should always return objects of similar kinds, and signal errors using exceptions.
3. `safeOpen` swallows exceptions and is therefore less safe than the builtin `open`.
4. `inputFile.predicate` tries to read an attribute called `predicate` from the file object `inputFile`. This will produce an `AttributeError` since no such predicate exists. If you want to pass a predicate function to the function, call it as `predicate(object)`.
5. `predicate == True` only works if `predicate` is a Boolean value, which is not what you want.
6. The line counting doesn't actually count the lines copied.

Comment: 1-3)
Honestly, I'm just going by what my professor has specified in his assignment. He asked for loops, try, and return statements, and to basically look at his code from class and attempt to mimic it.
4)
fixed that..kind of
5)
what is it that I want?
6)
fixed that

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that there is another module that is imported, called choices, with functions that return booleans. These are the "predicates" my prof. specified.